# I am sending image from action to view but getting error in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to retrieve image (`varbinary`) from SQL Server database and trying to display it using a linq query.

Here's my action controller:

```
public ActionResult show_pics()
{
    DBEntities db = new DBEntities();

    // get one image::
    byte[] item = (from f in db.Images
                   where f.Name.Contains("5.jpg")
                   select f.ImageContent).First();

    // get an image bytes
    var a = byteArrayToImage(item); //image.dal

    return View(a);
}
```

Here's my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Cygenus_website.Models.images>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "show_pics";
}

<h2>View_photos</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
       @foreach(var item in Model)
        {
            <td>
                @{
                    // converting to string
                    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.ImageBytes);
                    var imgsrc = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64);
                }

                <img src="@imgsrc" style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px" />
            </td>
 }
```

I get an exception:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Cygenus_website.Models.images]'.

I know that I am passing image to view whereas it's accepting `IEnumerable` but I don't know what to do as how to convert image to `IEnumerable` or any other solution?

Thanks.

P.s I am new to ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Can we see the code for `byteArrayToImage()`

Comment: public System.Drawing.Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
            System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
            return returnImage;
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
    @model IEnumerable<byte[]>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "show_pics";
}

<h2>View_photos</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
       @foreach(var item in Model)
        {
            <td>
                @{
                    // converting to string
                    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item);
                    var imgsrc = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64);
                }

                <img src="@imgsrc" style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px" />
            </td>
 }

    public ActionResult show_pics()
{
    DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
    // get one image::
    List<byte[]> images= (from f in db.Images
                   where f.Name.Contains("5.jpg")
                   select f.ImageContent).ToList();

    // get an image bytes
    //var a = byteArrayToImage(item); //image.dal

    return View(images);
}
```

Comment: Now can u tell me how to display all images in database through this approach?